# My program is looping infinitely, and I'm honestly not sure why

Tags: c

So the problem here was to write a program that uses pointers to point to functions and write it in such a way that it collects 10 doubles, gives feedback to the user of the program, sorts them and print the sorted results as proof. The problem is, the program either prints the printf statement in the beginning infinitely, or collects numbers infinitely.

Here is some code

```
#include <stdio.h>


void func1(double x);
void below_five(void);
void above_five(void);
void other(void);
void sort(double *p[], int n);
void print_doubles(double *p[], int n);

int main(void){

  double *numbers[9];
  int nbr;
  printf("\nEnter 10 doubles that are less than 5 or greater than 5, type 0 to exit");
  for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
  {

      scanf("%d", &nbr);
      func1(nbr);
      numbers[i] = nbr;

      if(nbr == 0)
        break;


  }
  sort(numbers, 10);
  print_doubles(numbers, 10);
  return 0;
}

void func1(double val)
{
  double (*ptr)(void);

  if(val <= 5.00){
    ptr = below_five;
  }else if((val > 5.00) && (val <= 10.00)){
    ptr = above_five;
  }else
    ptr = other;
}

void below_five(void){
  puts("You entered a number below or equal to five");
}

void above_five(void){
  puts("You entered a number above five");
}

void other(void){
  puts("You entered a number well above five.");
}

void sort(double *p[], int n)
{
double *tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if(p[i] > p[i+1]){
  tmp = p[i];
  p[i] = p[i+1];
  p[i + 1] = tmp;
}
}
}

void print_doubles(double *p[], int n)
{
  int count;
  for(count = 0; count < n; count++)
    printf("%d\n", p[count]);

}
```

Like I said, what I expect it to be able to do is collect doubles into the scanf method and then  print the numbers after sorting them, but it seems the for loop collects doubles forever without end in this case.

What have I done wrong, exactly?

Comment: First, turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. Second `double *numbers[9];` defines an array of nine elements, but you use ten. Third, its elements are pointers to `double`, but you assign a non-pointer `int` to them. Change `double *` to `double` there and elsewhere.

Comment: Fourth, the loop in your sort code will access beyond the end of the array. Fifth, one loop is not enough to sort completely. Sixth, you apparently want to read `double` values but are reading `int` values. Change the conversion specifier in `scanf` and change `nbr` from `int` to `double`.

Comment: Let me see if I can fix that sorting loop issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comments in your *updated* code. 
 <sub>There are other modifications required, but the minimum updates needed to work your code is below</sub>

```
#include <stdio.h>


void func1(double x);
void below_five(void);
void above_five(void);
void other(void);
    void sort(double p[], int n);  /* Simply use a array notation, 
arrays passed to functions decays to pointer */
    void print_doubles(double p[], int n); /* Simply use a array notation,
 arrays passed to functions decays to pointer */

int main(void){

  double numbers[10];
  double nbr; // Change type to double, as you're reading doubles
  printf("\nEnter 10 doubles that are less than 
           5 or greater than 5, type 0 to exit\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
  {

      scanf("%lf", &nbr); // Use correct format specifier to read doubles
      func1(nbr);
      numbers[i] = nbr;

      if(nbr == 0)
        break;


  }
  sort(numbers, 10);
  print_doubles(numbers, 10);
  return 0;
}

void func1(double val)
{
  double (*ptr)(void);

  if(val <= 5.00){
    ptr = below_five;
  }else if((val > 5.00) && (val <= 10.00)){
    ptr = above_five;
  }else
    ptr = other;
  /* Why you set the pointer to function if you don't call it, 
     so call it here*/    
        (*ptr)();  
    }

void below_five(void){
  puts("You entered a number below or equal to five");
}

void above_five(void){
  puts("You entered a number above five");
}

void other(void){
  puts("You entered a number well above five.");
}

void sort(double p[], int n)  /* Your sorting routine is wrong ,
   see the modified code */
{
double tmp;
    for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
    for(int i = 0; i < n-j-1; i++)
{
  if(p[i] > p[i+1]){
  tmp = p[i];
  p[i] = p[i+1];
  p[i + 1] = tmp;
}
}
}

void print_doubles(double p[], int n)
{
  int count;
  for(count = 0; count < n; count++)
    printf("%lf\n", p[count]); // Use correct format specifier

}
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](https://rextester.com/NSLKRV93899)</kbd>

Comment: @Matthew_J_Barnes, so what is the point of setting it in the first place? You should know better? You only point to a proper function handler, but never call it. If you don't call it using () notation, your set function handler won't' trigger automagically

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your superior help and time. Secondly, I'm a bit confused : The point of setting it in the first place and calling it long after it has been set are two different points, I'd really appreciate it if you could explain that one to me. Calling it to begin with should suffice, right? So, why do I need to call it again when I don't need to call a pointer again in say. . . main ?